# How to create ScalaZ Task which is running asynchronously right after creation?

Tags: scala, asynchronous, task, scalaz

I need Scalaz `Task` (or some wrapper) which is already running, and can return value immediately if it is completed, or after some waiting if it is not. In terms of `Future` I could do it like this:

```
val f = myTask.get.started
```

This way I have `Future` running asynchronously, which on `f.run` returns result immediately when called after the computation is complete, or blocks for some time and waits for completion if it is not. However, this way I loose error handling.

How to have `Task` and not use `Future`, but still have it already running asynchronously *before* `run`, or `runAsync` is called on it?

Answer (score 0):

The intention of `scalaz.Task` is clear control over the execution, which makes referential transparency possible. If you want to fork off the `Task`, use:

```
val result = Task.fork(myTask)
```

and the task will run in its own threadpool as soon as you run it with one of the `unsafe*` methods.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't solve my problem. Still, it's not running until someone calls `run` on it. I need a task which, when called enough time after it's creation, returns the value immediately (because in the time given it was computed asynchronously). This is not the case with `fork` if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: It's working as intended. If you want something that runs without your explicit statement, use a `Future`.